# Spark Dataframe producing 2 files after repartition to 1

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, distributed-computing

Hello People of the internet,

I have the below piece of spark function that I use in my batch job to write to s3.

```
def writeOneCsvFile(df:Dataframe, s3Location:string) = {
df.repartition(1)
 .write
 .partitionBy("date_column")
 .format("csv")
 .option("header",true).option("quoteAll",true)
 .save(s3Location) }
```

What I'm trying to do basically, is to write only 1 file per partition on s3. Now, I use the same piece of code to write 3 dataframes to 3 separate s3 locations.

Dataframe 1 writes 2 files, one about 260mb and the other 80mb. 
Dataframe 2 writes 1 file of about 75 mb.
Dataframe 3 writes 1 file of about  3 gb.

What I'm trying to understand is, for dataframe 1, why is spark writing 2 files and
why for dataframe 2 and 3, its writing only 1 file?
And, what can I do to make spark write only 1 file per partition every time, no matter the dataframe.

Also, not that it matters, but for a given run, the date_column's value is always 1 value for all the records, regardless of which ever dataframe it is.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since you are decreasing the number of partitions, did you try `coalesce` instead of `repartition`?

Comment: `Also, not that it matters, but for a given run, the date_column's value is always 1 value for all the records, regardless of which ever dataframe it is.` It does matter because the [DataFrameWriter.partitionBy()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.html#partitionBy-scala.collection.Seq-) can split each of the original partitions into multiple partitions depending on values in the columns that you specified. Could you please provide a recursive listing of the S3 location that the data frame 1 was written to?

Answer (score 0):

I had the below property set up when building the spark context object which was causing this issue. So, 1 file has 5M rows and the rest of the rows go to another file.

```
spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile=5000000
```